# Why is apache running in the background?

Tags: 12.10, services

I didn't install apache.  I also have ssh installed.

Do apache and ssh come by default with Ubuntu?

I do have LAMPP but I thought I had kept it disabled. 
Yet, I can see an apache initial page that shows that it's working.

Comment: Neither apache or ssh-server are installed by default. To disable apache you can use `sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove`. If you want to enable it at system startup again you can use `sudo update-rc.d apache2 defaults`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache got installed when I installed "libapache2-mod-mono".
It's a package which you can use to deploy aspx pages. It installs apache2.2 and all apache dependencies you need to run a simple web server.

The default path of server will be "/var/www"

I unknowingly did that. If you need to remove apache 2.2 then you have to remove only "libapache2-mod-mono" and it will remove apache2.2 and its dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

Apache does not install by default (But it could be installed with another program if apache is a depedency). If apache is running anyone can connect to it (If you have not blocked)

If you don't want apache, run `sudo apt-get remove apache2` to uninstall it.

If you want to stop apache from starting at boot time, run `sudo update-rc.d apache2 remove`

On systemd, the apache server is disabled with `sudo systemctl disable apache2.service` and stopped writing `sudo systemctl stop apache2.service`.

Comment: How can i stop it and restart as needed ? I made a search on my system and I found It comes with the NetBeans installation. NetBeans needs apache for PHP applications.

Comment: run sudo update-rc.d apache2 remove to stop it from starting at boot time. When you want to start it run /etc/init.d/apache2 start. run /etc/init.d/apache2 stop to stop it.